# How do I forward a message sent to me on Gmail?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

Is there a specific way in Python that I can forward a message that was sent from someone to my account on Telegram, for example

In other words, he directs the message to be received by mail to the place I specify?

Answer (score 1):

You could try and set up [Enabling auto-forwarding](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/forwarding_settings?hl=en)

```
from __future__ import print_function

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def enable_forwarding():
    """Enable email forwarding.
    Returns:Draft object, including forwarding id and result meta data.

    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
    """
    creds, _ = google.auth.default()

    try:
        # create gmail api client
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        address = {'forwardingEmail': 'gduser1@workspacesamples.dev'}

        # pylint: disable=E1101
        result = service.users().settings().forwardingAddresses(). \
            create(userId='me', body=address).execute()
        if result.get('verificationStatus') == 'accepted':
            body = {
                'emailAddress': result.get('forwardingEmail'),
                'enabled': True,
                'disposition': 'trash'
            }
            # pylint: disable=E1101
            result = service.users().settings().updateAutoForwarding(
                userId='me', body=body).execute()
            print(F'Forwarding is enabled : {result}')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        result = None

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enable_forwarding()
```